# Regex to have atleast 1 character and 1 number

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to make a Regex such that it's min length is 8 and max length is 25 and it should contain at least 1 `[A-Za-z]` and at least 1 `[0-9]`

Here is what I came up with:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^.+${8,25}(?<=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])");

var test = regex.IsMatch("testadasd9");
```

But it is not working. As you can see I am using positive look behind. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is REGEX required? Maybe using standard c# string functions, it would be much easier and more clearer.

Comment: sorry, regex is required as I want this to be used in Asp.Net regular expression validator

Comment: Jack thats a little bit of a strange reason to need regex... What does "not working" mean?

Comment: not working meant it was returning false for a string which should have returned true. Not sure what is the confusion that you have.

Comment: @Sayse full ack - one could also use `CustomValidator` and do some fancy stuff in the eventHandler ...

Comment: @Jack - Not working could mean a number of things: Code doesn't compile, your program crashes, you don't get the desired result, you get some desired results but also erroneous results, your program runs but your code is never reached, your program works on some computers but not others..... It seems like it produces some erroneous results but you never described them.

Comment: How did pwas and Avinash Raj understand if my 2 lines of code confused your mind so much?

Comment: Sorry if I'm way off, but if that's a password requirement, why limit it to only 25 characters? I like to use (badly spelt) passphrases which can easily get a lot longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match a string of minimum length 8 and max length 25 and also the string must contain atleast one literal `[A-Za-z]` and atleast one digit.

```
^(?=.{8,25}$)(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yR1qN5/2)

Comment: Couldn't it be changed instead to new Regex("(?=.{8,25}$)(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])"); for clarity?

Comment: I don't get how those positive lookaheads can work. The content of the lookaheads makes sense, but how it can select the whole string with .* afterwards when the first lookahead already includes the whole string??? Interesting you can use an end mark `$` in a lookaround part, however I'm confused.

Comment: Oh wow, now I got it. Those lookaheads matching the "nothing" that is followed by the required content of those lookaheads, so "nothing" is selected when all those lookaheads are true, but then you can select all by using `.*` at the end. Is any lookahead not true, `.*` will never be reached, so you can determine a condition for the whole string with lookaheads when using the start mark `^`, how cool.

Comment: @modiX lookaheads are used for condition checking and also lookaheads should do a zero width match. See the first lookahead `^(?=.{8,25}$)`, it matches the start(zero width) and then checks the condition given in the lookahead that there must be a min of 8 and max of 25 chars only because it is immediately followed by the line end anchor `$` then it moves to next looakheads... String would be matched only when all the lookaheads are true.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yea, basically I know what the content does. I just mixed lookahead with lookbehind again. So this makes sense. However, thank you for clarify.