# On Demand Regular Expression for Password

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I need to make a regular expression for password, whose strength settings can be changed by the client. The strength parameters are as follows:

[image]

Min and Max length can be taken care of by AngularJS ngMinlength and ngMaxlength.

But I need to generate a regular expression which will be created on the fly, by parameters fetched from the db.

I can fetch these parameters from a JSON like this:

```
var minCharLength = pwdJSON.minCharLength;
var minCapCharLength = pwdJSON.minCapCharLength;
...
var regex = // What to do now?
```

I don't have the knowledge of regular expression making. Plus this regular expression will also be used for validating on server with C#.

Comment: Try to separating the logic of validating special characters and validating minimums or length (which can be done without regex more easily)

Comment: even i am thinking of doing it without regex..

Comment: @AvinashRaj only think i cud try is from one of your answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25520295/1127787

it allows one char and on num..but i dont knw how to make it work for N char and N numbers

Comment: I am sure angular supports ajax callbacks for validation in some way, so you could just have a simple validation function on the server side and call that, returning json in the form it expects.  Since the validation rules already live on the server, that seems the best way, and you would be guaranteed a consistent response. You could combine it with client side validation (min/max) and only fire the ajax one after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
^(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z].*){6})(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){1})(?=(?:.*[0-9].*){2})(?:[a-zA-Z0-9*#$%]){8,16}$
```

Where you drop in the relevant limits (letters, capitals, numbers, min & max length) as well as the non-comma-separated special characters in the end

**EDIT** adding example with the variables... you just build up the string to the regex pattern, and then test with it

```
string regex = "^(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z].*){" + minCharLength + "})(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){" + minCapCharLength + "})(?=(?:.*[0-9].*){" + minNumLength + "})(?:[a-zA-Z0-9" + specialChars + "]){" +  overallMinLength + "," + overallMaxLength + "}$"; 
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(password, regex);
```

**EDIT2** - I thought an explanation might be appreciated :-)

- We are anchoring the regex to the whole string with `^` and `$`
- Each test is a positive lookahead `(?=  )` so it checks for existence but doesn't move the position

  - the test has the group `(?:.*[our_characterset].*){how_many_times}` - so a non-capturing group effectively searching for our characters at any point in the string (with the `.*`s) the right number of times
- Finally we get the allowed characters (including our special characters) having to exist between min and max length occurrences (using the `{m,n}`) (with the anchors)

And a regex pattern is just a string - so we can build it up using the variables from the form..

Comment: So you would have e.g. `string regex = "^(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z].*){" + minCharLength + "})(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){" + minCapCharLength + "})(?=(?:.*[0-9].*){" + minNumLength + "})(?:[a-zA-Z0-9" + specialChars + "]){" +  overallMinLength + "," + overallMaxLength + "}$";` and then `bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(password, regex);`

Comment: Nice @Captain I wrote it down in the form of an if and conditions for readability:  if (password.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9*#\$%]{8,16}\w*/g) && password.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9*#\$%]{8,16}\w*/g)[0].length == password.length && password.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length >= 6 && password.match(/[A-Z]/g).length >=1 && password.match(/[0-9]/g).length >=2) {
 alert(" you have an awesome password");   
}

Answer (score 0):

With a single regular expression you can tell the user that his password does not meet the security requirements. However, I would check each condition on its own. That allows you to print more expressive error messages like *"Your password must contain at least 8 characters."* or *"Your password must contain at least 2 capital letters."*

The length can be checked with the `string.Length` property.

For the other conditions, you could define a character class (brackets) for each and count the matches:

- count numbers: `Regex.Matches(password, "[0-9]").Count`
- count letters: `Regex.Matches(password, "[A-Za-z]").Count` (or `Regex.Matches(password,  "[\p{L}]" ).Count` if you want to allow letters like ä, Ö, ß as well)
- count capital letters: `Regex.Matches(password, "[A-Z]").Count`

The last condition (additional characters) requires a character class that is a combination of the above ones plus the additional characters that are specified in the input field:

```
string regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9(?#additional characters go here)]*$";
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(password, regex);
```

The additional characters must be added dynamically. You can use [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for escaping characters like `*` or `$`